# how to handle multiple time setstate in react (budget app)

Tags: reactjs, crud, setstate

[this is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNIfn.png)

i have study case to create budget app in react.
there is a form which contains 3 for input namely select type (expense, income), amount and title.
*nb pengeluaran=expense, pemasukan=income,jumlah=amount.

i have two components, i.e InputData for input data, TotalMoney for display total money,expense and income.

form for add data

```
<form onSubmit={this.countMoney}>
            <div className="form-group col-md-4">
              <label>Tipe</label>
              <select className="form-control" onChange={this.onChangeTipe}>
                <option>Pilih</option>
                <option value="pengeluaran">Pengeluaran</option>
                <option value="pemasukan">Pemasukan</option>
              </select>
            </div>

.......input value for amount and title
```

handler when onsubmit for Input Data

```
countMoney = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let items = {
      // id: this.state.itemLists.length + 1,
      tipe: this.state.tipe,
      jumlah: this.state.jumlah,
      judul: this.state.judul
    };

    this.setState(
      {
        jumlah: 0,
        judul: "",
        items: items,
        itemLists: [...this.state.itemLists, items]
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.tipe === "pengeluaran") {
          this.setState({
            pengeluaran: this.state.pengeluaran + items.jumlah,
            totalUang: this.state.totalUang - items.jumlah
          });
        } else if (this.state.tipe === "pemasukan") {
          this.setState({
            pemasukan: this.state.pemasukan + items.jumlah,
            totalUang: this.state.totalUang + items.jumlah
          });
        }
      }
    );
```

each item entered will be made an object and entered into the state itemLists

this is components to display data

```
function TotalMoney(props) {
  return (
    <div className="totalMoney">
      <div className="description">
        Total Pemasukan
        <div className="rupiah">{props.pemasukan}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="description">
        Total Pengeluaran
        <div className="rupiah">{props.pengeluaran}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="description">
        Total Uang
        <div className="rupiah">{props.totalUang}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i got problem when input data like this:

1. Pemasukan(income) = 20000
2. Pengeluaran(expense) = 10000
3. Pemasukan(income) = 20000
4. Pengeluaran(expense) = 5000

output must be

1. Total Pemasukan(income) = 40000
2. Total Pengeluaran(expense) = 15000
3. Total Uang(Money) = 25000

but the output is

1. Total Pemasukan(income) = 02000020000
2. Total Pengeluaran(expense) = 0100005000
3. Total Uang(Money) = 1000015000

for more complete this is my code
https://github.com/saldhyyoga/test/blob/master/src/components/InputData.js

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is that you're trying to add strings together. Usually the result of an input element is a string, trying running `parseInt` on the responses

Comment: i think so but i confused when i put parseInt ?

Comment: Change this line here https://github.com/saldhyyoga/test/blob/master/src/components/InputData.js#L44

to `tipe: parseInt(event.target.value, 10)`

Potentially will also need it in your other change handlers

Comment: why tipe must be parseInt, instead of tipe/type must be string('expense' or 'income') ?

Comment: My bad, I think it might be `onChangeJumlah` that needs the parseInt